# How to boot a NanoPC-T2 (FriendlyARM) from SD card without holding the boot key?

Tags: arm, embedded, embedded-linux, bootloader

I'm newbie at embedded.
How to boot **NanoPC-T2** from **SD Card** without holding the boot key?

Comment: Probably a question for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or the manufacturer's technical support.  Probably not an SO question.

Comment: I suggest you simply de-solder the BOOT-SEL switch and replace with a .1" pitch two pin SMT header and jumper (if it will fit) or fit a soldered SMT jumper, or simply solder a wire bridge across it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a hardware issue - there is no software solution.

Comment: @Clifford - **untrue** there are software solutions to this problem, not just hardware ones.  Which is most appropriate depends on the user's needs.  Since the hardware solution is succinctly explained, there's no value to moving the question to EESE where the software approach would be relatively off topic.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Fair enough, all things are possible;  jumping the switch is however *really* simple and reliable.  Given the admission of newbieness, I cannot see it being a solution Quasem would go for or that I would recommend in this case - better to spend time building interesting applications perhaps. I withdraw my vote however since the answer itself has value perhaps to others or if the need is not simply a one-off.  If for example this is for a volume product, the software solution may be preferred.

Comment: I agree the switch is useful for a quick test.  But U-Boot may already be installed.  And realistically, even if it isn't, someone not willing to learn to build and install that (or comparable tasks of building a kernel, file system, etc) is going to be someone who is fairly limited in what they will be able to accomplish with an embedded board overall.

Comment: Embedded systems running U-Boot and Linux are of course only a subset of all possible embedded systems.  Neither of which I would claim any great knowledge of (in 27 years of embedded systems development) - so I would say quite a lot can be achieved ;-)

Comment: @ChrisStratton :  I thought perhaps that the boot mechanism that selects SD or eMMC was a primary bootloader in mask ROM on the SoC, and not modifiable or configurable, and that U-Boot was included on the SD or eMMC as a secondary bootloader.  That is how devices I *have* used work - I did not look into this one that deeply.

Comment: U-Boot being installed as a secondary bootloader doesn't preclude it choosing where to load the ultimate running system from, assuming that the desired storage location is present and accessible.

Comment: @Clifford Assuming it's like the other Samsung SoCs I know of, the mask ROM simply tries to boot from whichever MMC controller the external config pins say, and will sit there stubbornly doing nothing in the absence of a card/eMMC on that specific interface. I do maintain that copying a U-boot image to eMMC and configuring its default bootcmd to load from SD (I can vouch for that working on an Exynos 5410 board) still falls firmly under _using a computer_, not programming; that said computer isn't a beige x86 box still doesn't bestow it any magic everything-is-programming-related powers ;)

Answer (score 2):

While hardware modification of the mode switch may be a quick fix, it is not your only option - purely software methods exist as well.

If the device by default boots from eMMC, then you can place an intermediate program on the eMMC which will in turn cause it to boot the real operating system from the SD card.

This is typically the role of a `bootloader` and a very common one on embedded systems is U-Boot.  U-Boot typically allows configuration such as where to boot the operating system from to be either compiled in, or modified after installation via serial console interaction and then saved as persistent configuration.

It is not entirely clear if your board *always* uses U-Boot and has it already installed on the eMMC (though booting with a serial console connected would probably reveal this), however what appears to be the [support WIKI](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/NanoPC-T2#Compile_U-Boot) for your board has instructions for building U-Boot for your board from an appropriate branch of:

https://github.com/friendlyarm/uboot_nanopi2/tree/nanopi2-lollipop-mr1

You would then need to configure U-Boot to automatically boot from the SD Card, and install U-Boot itself on the eMMC (if it is not already there).